# Does Arduino Tian/LininoOS support Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm using an Arduino Yun running OpenWRT and it only runs Python 2.7.

I need to find a microcontroller+processor+WiFi board that supports Python 3. Does the Arduino Tian work for this, or are there any others?

Comment: [OpenWRT supports Python 3.3](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=180214#p180214); is OpenWRT on the Yun less capable than elsewhere?  Also see [**Installing Python3**](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/software/python) section in Python page at openwrt.org

Comment: it is different. its based on a selfmade kind of openWRT. it does not have ./scripts/ and the path for opkg is: http://downloads.arduino.cc/openwrtyun/1/packages/Packages.gz
im searching for python3+

Comment: Linkit Smart 7688 Duo Yun compatible board has support for python3.4 with openWRT 15.05.1. But it lacks some of the nice Arduino stuf like REST API with YunServer/Bridge

Answer (score 1):

Yes, run the following

```
opkg update
opkg install python3-base_3.4.3-2_ar71xx.ipk
```

Comment: this does not work on Yun v1 nor on Arduino Industrial 101 im still searching for a greater version then 2.7 on one of those boards...